# how to use router inside codeigniter helper by ci instance like $CI->router->fetch_method()

Tags: php, codeigniter, helper

I try to create new method inside custom helper,

```
if ( ! function_exists('active_link'))
{
    function active_link($method_name)
    {
        if($CI->router->fetch_method()==$method_name){
            return 'active';
        }               
        return 'none';
    }   
}
```

the code dose not work, because I cant get the router by CI instance.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message:  Call to a member function
>   fetch_method() on null
>
> Filename: helpers/smart_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 8

Comment: I think you forget `$CI =& get_instance();` inside helper!!

Comment: No I already do that but it does not work.

Comment: <code>
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
  $CI =& get_instance();
 
 if ( ! function_exists('active_link'))
 {
     function active_link($method_name)
     {
      if($CI->router->fetch_method()==$method_name){
       return 'active';
      }       
         return 'none';
     }   
 }
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Instead of

```
$CI->router->fetch_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by moving the request of router to the view and pass the two parameters to the function:
in the helper

```
<?php    
    if ( ! function_exists('active_link'))
    {
        function active_link($feched_method,$method_name)
        {
            if($feched_method==$method_name){
                return 'active';
            }               
            return false;
        }   
    }
```

in the view:

```
<?php echo active_link($this->router->fetch_method(),'index');?>
```